# How to convert in place all zoned datetime objects within a list of dicts, to UTC ISO format?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of dicts as such, let's called it data_list:

```
[{"field1": 'blah blah', "field2": "2018-08-12T03:51:02.739000+00:00"},
{"field1": 'blah blah blah', "field2": "2018-10-11T03:51:02.739000+00:00"}]
```

I want to convert in-place all members of data_list that have datetime format containing zone and milliseconds to pure UTC ISO (i.e. 2020-10-10 12:00:00). I don't know ahead of time which fields will contain these datetime objects.

What might be an efficient way to do this? I'm also unsure of where to start as far as applying the encoding for this. Does the datetime library have a method for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) is the way to go here, if you don't know which field will be a date then you'll need to parse them all.

```py
from datetime import datetime

data_list = [{"field1": 'blah blah', "field2": "2018-08-12T03:51:02.739000+00:00"},
{"field1": 'blah blah blah', "field2": "2018-10-11T03:51:02.739000+00:00"}]

# With try/catch
def try_format_date(potential_date):
    try:
        return potential_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    except AttributeError:
        return potential_date
    
# with type checking
def try_format_date(potential_date):
    if isinstance(potential_date, datetime):
        return potential_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    return potential_date

data_list = [
    {key: try_format_date(value) for key, value in data.items()} 
    for data in data_list
]
data_list
# [{'field1': 'blah blah', 'field2': '2018-08-12 03:51:02'},
# {'field1': 'blah blah blah', 'field2': '2018-10-11 03:51:02'}]
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make this clear, but potential_date would be coming in as a datetime object.

Comment: Alright, I've made the edit, it's even simpler now :)